# Pig dump command getting stuck at 0%

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm working on an Ubuntu VM, I have a file A.txt which has a below data

```
1,2,3  
4,5,6
```

and I used below pig relation command:

```
a = load '/files/A.txt';
```

then I used the command below to dump a:

```
dump a;
```

but it is getting stuck at 0% completion. Please help.

Comment: Are you running Pig against YARN? Is the ResourceManager running?

Comment: check the hadoop/YARN logs during the execution.

Comment: Yes, Resource Manager is running.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with heap size or yarn parameter miss match. please check that one and confirm there is free memory available.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your not loading data appropriately using Pig.

Please find below approach to load data and dump it.

a = load '/files/A.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (x:int, y:int, z:int)

dump a;

Comment: We can load directly without the full command, however I had tried this but did not work. Thanks

Comment: We recommend to check the logs. You can find some thing in the logs.

Comment: Unable to get anything in logs. Pig is working fine in local mode but not in live mode.